# Return same row alternate column value after successful LARGE?

Tags: excel

I'm using `=LARGE(H5:H24,1)` to find the largest value in a column H. I also want the equivalent `Column A` value, i.e. If this formula returns `Column H` `Row 3`, I also want the `Column A` `Row 3` value (this can be returned to a different result/cell). I tried `VLookup` but keep getting errors in the formula. Thanks

Comment: what `vlookup` formula have you tried? Specifying column H value and getting back column A is not possible **as it will lookup the value on the 1st column** and return any column (1st or after)

Answer (score 1):

`=INDEX(A5:A24,MATCH(LARGE(H5:H24,1),H5:H24,0))`

Comment: Remember that MATCH function should be filled with last option -> 1, 0, -1. In case function MATCH will be looking for decimal places numbers, it could found not exactly the number we want to get. My proposition =INDEX(A5:A24,MATCH(LARGE(H5:H24,1),H5:H24,0))

Answer (score 0):

Other way to solve this:

+4 at the end because we start counting from 5th row.

```
=INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(LARGE(H5:H24;1);H5:H24;0)+4)
```

Comment: Thanks guys. '=INDEX(A5:A24,MATCH(LARGE(H5:H24,1),H5:H24,0))' did the trick perfectly!